# How to secure my Azure WebApp with the built-in authentication mechanism

Tags: python, azure, docker, authentication, flask

I created a Flask-Webservice with Python that runs independently inside a docker container. I then uploaded the docker image to an Azure Container Registry. From there I can create a WebService (for Containers) with some few clicks in the Azure Portal, that runs this container. So far so good. It behaves just as I want it to.

But of course I don't want anyone to access the service. So I need some kind if authentication. Luckily (or so I thought) there is a built-in authentication-mechanism (I think it is based on OAuth ... I am not that well versed in security issues). Its [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-overview) is a bit sparse on what actually happens and also concentrates on solutions in C#.

I first created a project with Google as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/app-service/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-google-authentication) and then configured the WebApp-Authentication with the Client-Id and Secret. I of course gave Google a java script source and callback-url, too.

When I now log off my Google account and try a GET-Request to my Webservice in the Browser (the GET should just return a "hello world"-String), I am greeted with a Login Screen ... just as I expected.

When I now login to Google again, I am redirected to the callback-url in the browser with some kind of information in the parameters.

> a token perhaps? It looks something like this:
>
> https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/google/callback?state=redirxxx&code=xxx&authuser=xxx&session_state=xxx&prompt=xxx).

Here something goes wrong, because an error appears.

> An error occurred.
>
> Sorry, the page you are looking for is currently unavailable.
>   Please try again later.
>
> If you are the system administrator of this resource then you should check the error log for details.
>
> Faithfully yours, nginx.

As far as I now, nginx is a server software that hosts my code. I can imagine that it also should handle the authentication process. It obviously lets all requests through to my code when authentication is turned off, but blocks un-authenticated accesses otherwise and redirects to the google login. Google then checks if your account is authorized for the application and redirects you to the callback with the access token along with it. This then returns a cookie which should grant my browser access to the app. (I am just reproducing the documentation here).

So my question is: What goes wrong. Does my Browser not accept the cookie. Did I something wrong when configuring Google+ or the Authentication in the WebApp. Do I have to use a certain development stack to use the authentication. Is it not supported for any of the technologies I use (Python, Flask...).

EDIT

@miknik:

In Microsofts documentation of the authentication/authorization it says

> The authentication and authorization module runs in the same sandbox
>   as your application code. When it's enabled, every incoming HTTP
>   request passes through it before being handled by your application
>   code.
>
> ...
>
> The module runs separately from your application code and is
>   configured using app settings. No SDKs, specific languages, or changes
>   to your application code are required.

So while you are probably right that the information in the callback-redirect is the authorization grant/code and that after that this code should now be used to get an access token from Google, I don't quite understand how this would work in my situation.

As far as I can see it Microsofts WebApp for Container-Resource on Azure should take care of getting the token automatically and return it as part of the response to the callback-request. The documentation states 4 steps:

> 1. Sign user in:  Redirects client to /.auth/login/.
> 2. Post-authentication: Provider redirects client to /.auth/login//callback.
> 3. Establish authenticated session: App Service adds authenticated cookie to response.
> 4. Serve authenticated content: Client includes authentication cookie in subsequent requests (automatically handled by browser).

It seems to me that step 2 fails and that that would be exactly what you wrote: that the authorization grant is to be used by the server to get the access token but isn't.

But I also don't have any control over that. Perhaps someone could clear things up by correcting me on some other things:

First I can't quite figure out which parts of my problem represent which role in the OAuth-scheme.

- I think I am the **Owner**, and by adding users to the list in the Google+-Project I authorize them to use my service.
- Google is obviously the **authorization server**
- my WebService (or better yet my WebApp for Containers) is the **resource server**
- and finally an application or postman that does the requests is the **Client**

In the descriptions of OAuth I read the problematic step boils down to: the *resource server* gets the access token from the *authorization server* and passes it along to the *client*. And Azures WebApps Resource is prompted (and enabled) to do so by being called with the callback-url. Am I right somewhere in this?

Alas, I agree that I don't quite understand the whole protocol. But I find most descriptions on the net less than helpful because they are not specific to Azure. If anyone knows a good explanation, general or Azure-specific, please make a comment.

Comment: You are in over your head. You need to do some research into Oauth2. It's industry standard and well documented all over the internet Your understanding sounds about right up until the point Google "redirects you to the callback with the access token". All you have at this point is an authorization code, it's now up to your server to provide your app credentials to Google and exchange the code for an access token,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to make it work and I try to explain what went wrong as good as I can. Please correct me if I go wrong or use the wrong words.

As I suspected the problem wasn't so much that I didn't understand OAuth (or at least how Azure manages it) but the inner workings of the Azure WebApp Service (plus some bad programming on my part). Azure runs an own Server and is not using the built-in server of flask. The actual problem was that my flask-program didn't implement a WSGI-Interface. As I could gather this is another standard for python scripts to interact with any server. So while rudimentary calls from the server (I think Azure uses nginx) were possible, more elaborate calls, like the redirect to the callback url went to dev/null.

I build a new app following [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-python) and then secured it by following the [authentication/authorization-tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-overview) and everything worked fine. The code in the tutorial implements WSGI and is probably more conform to what Azure expects. My docker solution was too simple.

My conclusion: read up on this WSGI-standard that flask always warned me about and I didn't listen and implement it in any code that goes beyond fiddeling around in development.